# How to set the value of a SettingKey based on different sbt commands?

Tags: sbt, flyway

There's the command `sbt flywayMigrate` from flywaydb.org.  The command requires use to set `flywayUrl`, `flywayUser`, and `flywayPassword` beforehand. It was good so far.

Now I want to be able to use `sbt flywayMigrate` for two different environment; Their variables should be different.

I tried to make two new commands: `sbt flywayMigrateDev` and `sbt flywayMigrateProd`. I couldn't figure out how to connect the new commands to `flywayMigrate`.

I tried creating a new scope. But I couldn't figure out how to wire the  variables and tasks properly.

I wonder if anyone can give me an example on how to do this. I'd like to see a code example.

We can simplify the problem to:

There's the command `sbt flywayMigrate` that depends on `flywayUrl`. How do we allow the command to use different `flywayUrl`s by calling sbt commands (or any other way is good, too)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `config` for this.

Example `.sbt` file contents:

```scala
// Set up your configs.
lazy val prodConfig = config("prod")
lazy val devConfig = config("dev")

// Set up any configuration that's common between dev and prod.

val commonFlyway = Seq(
  // For the sake of example, a couple of shared settings.
  flywayUser := "pg_admin",
  flywayLocations := Seq("filesystem:migrations")
)

// Set up prod and dev.
inConfig(prodConfig)(flywayBaseSettings(prodConfig) ++ commonFlyway)
flywayUrl.in(prodConfig) := "jdbc:etc:proddb.somecompany.com"
// Or however you want to load your production password.
flywayPassword.in(prodConfig) := sys.env.getOrElse("PROD_PASSWD", "(unset)")

inConfig(devConfig)(flywayBaseSettings(prodConfig) ++ commonFlyway)
flywayUrl.in(devConfig) := "jdbc:etc:devdb.somecompany.com"
flywayPassword.in(devConfig) := "development_passwd"
```

Now you can run `prod:flywayMigrate` and `dev:flywayMigrate` to migrate production and development, respectively.

See [the Flyway docs page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt/) for other examples.

Comment: I just asked another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738849/how-to-make-a-scope-for-dev-and-prod-for-one-command-in-sbt Thank you for suggesting a better solution here.

Comment: How have you learned how to do this? I was browsing through SBT document but couldn't figure it out. I'd love to learn how you've learned it.

Comment: The old example code was exactly what I had in my own `sbt` configuration. I've updated the example code to match the newest version of the Flyway plugin, and added a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Which version of plugin were you using this with?